# HTML validator errors for all head meta-tags, why?

Tags: html, validation

I ran my HTML trough a validator and was horrorfied to see around 80 errors despite the site working quite fine. Please see the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="da-DK">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<titel>Restauranter i København med havudsigt</titel>
</head>
<body>
Hi there
</body>
</html>
```

To this, the validator says, among other things, that there is no titel no, attribute charset not allowed on element meta, element meta is missing one or more of the following attributes and so forth.

But I a titel in the head part, and the titel is not part of the body.
Does anyone know why on earth this is happening?

Edit: Thank you. For future reference, it is a good idea to run HTML trough a quick english-spellcheck to "catch" mistakes such as this. I believed the english word "title" was spelled "titel" like it is in Danish.

Comment: might it be a typo in `title`?

Comment: `<titel>` should be `<title>`

Comment: Would you mind providing the validator you are using? Does it recognise HTML5 as the type to validate? The errors about the `<meta charset` indicate that this might not be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem:

`<titel>Restauranter i København med havudsigt</titel>`

titel instead of title

Comment: That is.. so emberassing. Thank you so much for spotting that so quickly. After fixing the title I went from 80 errors in the validator to 6 (all of them due to me messing up my responsive tabel) THAT, I can work with - seems less intimidating to start fixing my mistakes now

Comment: You are welcome! This things happen